# Effect of email offer - did buy /did not buy; and spending amount, Chi square, ANOVA, R, TSQL

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test

Customers who bought product A in the past are offered supplementary product B by email. They are split into 3 groups:

1. Did not get email offer, (about 60.000 population)
2. Did get email offer and opened mail, (about 30.000 population)
3. Did get email offer and did not open mail). (about 30.000 population)

---

- I know whether they bought something and for how much.
- I also know the size of these original groups.

What sort of test would I use to evaluate these hypotheses:

- The mailing had an effect - more customers came into shop (Bought
  something T/F)
- The mailing had an effect - customers spend more. (Did spend x
  money.)

It can be two separate analyses. My initial guesses are ANOVA or CHI square. I am using R / excel / tsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminary remarks**

In general, I would be very careful with assuming your observations are independent and identically distributed. In particular, business count data ("how many products bought") usually does not follow normal distribution.

Do you plan to take into consideration other factors that may affect your response variable ("they bought something and for how much")? I would suggest that in such business cases there might be multiple additional confounding variables:

- how long the client is with you,
- via what channel he reached the website,
- what are his previous purchases,
- type of a product purchased,

etc.

**Inference idea**

Having this stated, you can try to model the response variable with a model that incorporates (as explanatory variables) information about:

- the `customer_group` the customer was assigned to (levels: `with_mail`, `without_mail` etc.),
- other variables, for example such as outlined above,

and ***infer about statistical significance of being assigned to a particular level of a*** `customer_group`.

- A technical remark: in particular, if there might be several different actions taken (`long_email_sent`, `short_email_sent` etc.), it is convenient to set the one which refers to "no action" (here: `without_mail`) as a reference level for such a factor variable.

**Modelling tools**

The models you can think of are, starting from less and moving to more advanced:

1. Logistic Regression - model with a 0/1 response stating whether or not any product has been purchased by a customer,
2. Poisson Regression - model with a count response stating how many products has been purchased (0 including),
3. Negative Binomial regression / Zero-Inflated Poisson Regression - model with a count response stating how many products has been purchased (0 including), used to model count data that has an excess of zero counts (what is indeed typical in business cases),
4. Generalized Linear Mixed Model (e.g. Poisson model with a random intercept) - model with a count response, which is adequate for clustered data (you can consider "clusters" as a different groups of products which differ from each other by *general* demand you observe).

Comment: All your points are valid, the customer is indeed affected by confounding variables. And indeed the count data does not follow normal distribution. Neither the amount spent follows the normal distribution. So simple classical test such as CHi or ANova is out of the way then?

Comment: **Rigolletto**, I would use Chi-square test of independence to measure "success"/"no-success" rate differences between groups (here a group is either `without_mail` or `with_email`) *only* if I was sure that these groups are homogeneous in terms  of confounding variables; in other words, if I knew that proportions of let's say some important variable's levels (very attractive sale channel or something) are the same among groups. If in your case mailing groups are randomized that way (very rare, unfortunately), than it should work.

Comment: The same story (homogeneous of other confounding variables between groups) for Anova. In addition, if you want to model some continuous / count data that is hardly following a normal distribution, you can follow i.e. [cheat-sheet table from here](http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/dealing-non-normal-data-strategies-and-tools/) which gives you suggestions of Statistical Analysis Tools for Non-Normally Distributed Data. Anyway, given a model summary and (Non-Normally Distributed Data) test result summary, I would rather go for inference from a model.